# A simple script for submitting jobs on a server

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, shell-script, nohup

I'm trying to write a simple script to "submit jobs" on a server without a job queuing system. In bash terminal, I figured I could use commands like `nohup` to achieve this, e.g.:

```
nohup bash -c 'echo "Hello world" > foo.out' &>/dev/null
```

However, I want to implement this as a bash command, so I could do the above with, say

```
bgrun 'echo "Hello world" > foo.out'
```

Now, I got stuck writing the bash script for this. So here's what I've got:

```
#!/bin/bash

cmd="bash -c '$*'" 
nohup $cmd &>/dev/null
```

Now if I run the above, the output was directed to `/dev/null` instead of `foo.out`. Is there any way to get round this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

cmd="bash -c '$*'"
nohup $cmd > /tmp/foo.out
```

I executed it as below:

```
sh -x nohup.sh ls
```

I can see the o/p of `/tmp/foo.out` has list of files.

Comment: Hi, this is not what I want. I want the destination of redirection (if any) to be given in the command, not hard-coded in the script.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I can achieve what I want with `eval`:

```
#!/bin/bash

cmd="nohup bash -c '$*' &>/dev/null &" 
eval $cmd
```